# android- application/service visible is running services even after application is closed

Tags: android

I've created an android app which runs an activity and a service.

I've stopped the service in ondestroy() function of the activity.

But even when the application is closed & ondestroy() is called, the process is still visible in Settings -> applications -> running services.

How should I close it completely?

Code I'm using to start the service:

```
// initService is called from onCreate() in MainActivity
public void initService() {
    try {
        serviceConnection = new CallService();
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent();
        serviceIntent.setClassName("com.example.working",
                com.example.working.MyService.class.getName());
        boolean ret = this.bindService(serviceIntent, serviceConnection,
                Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Service bound : " + ret,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();         // Return true or false
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "initService(): " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
}

class CallService implements ServiceConnection {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder boundInterface) {
        try {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Service Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            aidlObject = WorkingAidl.Stub.asInterface((IBinder) boundInterface);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onServiceConnected: " + e.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName paramComponentName) {
        aidlObject = null;
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Service Disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: how do u start the service ? plz post code

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#stopService(android.content.Intent) "Note that if a stopped service still has ServiceConnection objects bound to it with the BIND_AUTO_CREATE set, it will not be destroyed until all of these bindings are removed."

Comment: unbindService did u use this method in ondestroy ? or call stopservice or what plz post that code as well and also oncreate method code